# What happened to the scene in Babylon 5 where Kosh kills the NaKaleen Feeder?

Tags: alternate-version, babylon-5

When I watched Babylon 5 for the first time --- when it first aired --- I distinctly remember a scene towards the end of the "Grail" episode in season 1, when Station personnel are trying to kill the NaKaleen Feeder.  Try as they might, the PPGs were having little effect.  Then, out of nowhere, Kosh shows up and starts shooting lightning bolts from his encounter suit, finally killing the Feeder.  Later, when he is questioned as to why he did it, he responds in his usual cryptic form by saying something like 'we do not do such things'.

I thought the scene was absolutely perfect for the episode.  It intensified our curiosity about what exactly was hidden by Kosh's encounter suit --- which was part of the goal of the episode, I thought.  And further, Kosh's response was masterfully ambiguous: Did Kosh say that Vorlons are not Feeders (and that therefore they do not feed like Feeders), or did he say that Vorlons are Feeders (or not too far removed from Feeders), but that they simply do not go about eating people's minds --- though they could potentially do so if they wanted to?  This scene with Kosh's answer ABSOLUTELY makes me --- the viewer who has not yet  discovered the truth about Vorlons --- intensely curious (and a little afraid) about what they truly are.

So, why did the scene disappear from the series?  The scene is not in the DVD episodes.  And furthermore, its disappearance creates a jarring effect: one moment the station personnel is shooting the a yellow-brownish Feeder, and the next moment the a wilted-yellow Feeder is lying in the bulkhead floor.  In my memory, the transition from a live Feeder to a dead Feeder was much more continuous in the scene where Kosh kills the Feeder.  Where did this scene go?  Or am I mis-remembering entirely and the scene was never shot?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it looks like a version of these scene that you're describing was *planned*, but I can't find any record of it ever being *shot*.

From **jms speaks** in [The Lurker's Guide](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/015.html):

> In an earlier version of the story, it was indeed Kosh who appeared
>   out of nowhere and scragged the Feeder, saying, "Some things we do not
>   allow," but it seemed kinda un-Kosh-like on one level, and it repeated
>   the Deathwalker finish*, so it was dropped.

(*where the Vorlon ship appears through the gate and blasts Deathwalker's ship before she can jump.)

This sounds like the scene was removed in the planning/writing stages, rather than after being shot and released.

Here's the actual dialogue when Sinclair speaks to real Kosh at the episode's end:

> Sinclair: We've confiscated the fake encounter suit. It's a pretty
>   close match to your own, at least from the outside.
>
> Kosh: Why?
>
> Sinclair: Deuce wanted to make people think he had the Vorlons working
>   for him. He figured it would add to his image and intimidate people.
>
> Kosh: Why?
>
> Sinclair: Well, after all, no one knows exactly what you look like.
>   That makes some people a little nervous.
>
> Kosh: Good.